# Froala character Count with meteor

Tags: meteor, froala

I had to disable the plugin in Froala. I am trying to use the character count option to allow displaying the data I require. My code looks like this so far.

```
Template.hello.helpers ({
    'counter': function(){
       return $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor('charCounter.count');
           }
        });
```

On the client side I refer to the helper like so:

```
<template name="hello">
{{counter}}
</template>
```

I know for a fact that `"$('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor('charCounter.count')"` works because I attached it to an event (button click) and was able to display the count in the console.

How do I go about displaying this data in my template?

Comment: Maybe the value for `$('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor('charCounter.count');` is set after the helper loads and displays. You could setup a hello.onCreated() function and then do `Session.set('count', $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor('charCounter.count'))` and then return that value ( `Session.get('count')` ) in your helper.

Comment: I though about that, but instead of session i used reactive variable as follows.  
on template create- I declared the reactive variable.
In the helper---- return counter.get()
under event I created a button that loads the value to the variable.( I checked if the value does indeed get loaded using console, and it does)

Comment: And it still doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah, still doses not work,  I printed a string with the helper, that works...but just not the counter values.

Comment: Your certain that `$('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor('charCounter.count')` displays a value? if you paste that into the JS inspect element console it gives you the right value? Also, you should update your code using reactvar.

Comment: yes i copy paste that code into console, it works. I have been updating the reactive var with a key press event and using counter.set()